# Issue with path to python/pythonpath

Tags: python, apache, unix, path, fastcgi

I have a VPS with system-wide installed python 2.5. 
I installed python 2.7 to one of the user's home dir (using --prefix). added it to bashrc and bash_profile, exported python variable to env, and now when I type python in console python 2.7 is running.
But when I checked python version from my application (Django using with FastCGI) I still see that it is using 2.5. 
In ps output I see python processes running for this account and apache processes runing with hosting-specific account. How can I switch this particular account to 2.7 without changing system-wide version?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a call to python interpreter via **env** program in my fast cgi dispatch script. When I explicitly put path to 2.7 to the first line of the script it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the python [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) tool to create a Python virtual environment that you can source in your `.bashrc`.

```
mike@tester:~$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 $HOME/fcgi_python
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in fcgi_python/bin/python3
Also creating executable in fcgi_python/bin/python
Installing Setuptools..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing Pip.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.

mike@tester:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.5+

mike@tester:~$ source $HOME/fcgi_python/bin/activate

(fcgi_python)mike@tester:~$ python --version
Python 3.3.2+
```

In the example above you would replace the argument after `--python=` with the path to the Python interpreter installed in the user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've set PYTHONPATH in my /home/me/.bashrc and all worked ok from terminal, but when Apache w/ mod_wsgi starts my python scripts, it acts under sysem or dedicated user, which knows nothing of my .bashrc.

For this particular situation, I just used apache config (**apache2.conf**) to set python path for apache (**WSGIPythonPath** option).